# Display object for Django Context Processors

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working to add some business details as a context processor within an app called `Business`. I've included in it a folder titled `templatetags` for the `__init__.py` and `business_tags.py` files. My problem is while the context processor shows a result, I am unable to display the results as a loop.

business_tags.py file:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ..models import Businessprofile

@register.simple_tag
def my_biz(request):
    current_user = request.user.id
    biz = Businessprofile.objects.filter(owner=current_user)

    return biz
```

On my view file I am currently made a for/endfor for the loop:

```
<!--content--> 
{% load business_tags %} 

{% my_biz request %}

{% for biz in my_biz %}
    {{ biz }}
{% endfor %}
<!--end content-->
```

How do I display the results of the context processor as a for loop?

Comment: Why do you keep talking about context processors when this is clearly a template tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your simple tag is just returning the object (it is not saved in "my_biz"), you need to save the return in a variable in this way:

```
{% my_biz request as my_biz_var %}

{% for biz in my_biz_var %}
    {{ biz }}
{% empty %}
    my_biz_var is empty
{% endfor %}
```

**Aditional note**: as is pointed by Daniel Roseman, what you are doing is not a context processor but a simple tag.

**context procesors:**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext

**Simple tags:**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags